# ImportError: No module named goose

Tags: python, virtualenv, pycharm, goose

Im trying to work with [Python-Goose extractor](https://github.com/grangier/python-goose). I Installed virtualenv, and followed the setup instructions. When running from PyCharm everything works great.

But when running from the Windows Command Prompt I'm getting this error:

```
C:\Users\tal>C:\virtual_enviroments\goose_venv\Scripts\activate
(goose_venv) C:\Users\tal>cd C:\main\prototypes\collection\goose-cli\app

(goose_venv) C:\main\prototypes\collection\goose-cli\app>extract-new-events.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\main\prototypes\collection\goose-cli\app\extract-new-events.py", line 1, in <module>
    from goose import Goose
ImportError: No module named goose
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Here is an image of it working in PyCharm [(large)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31tCy.png):

[image: Working in PyCharm.]

Comment: Also, it's very hard to read the tiny text in the screenshot of your PyCharm window. Are you actually using the same virtualenv, with the same settings, in PyCharm and in cmd? And running from the same working directory?

Comment: @abarnert I'm pretty sure thats what Im doing. Please take a look on the large screenshot and tell me if Im wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure why, but after adding "python" at the beginning it worked. like that:

```
python extract-new-events.py
```

Now its working...

Answer (score 0):

I cannot read the text on image as it's too small. But this is most likely your mistake:

- You have installed Goose to somewhere else than `goose_venv`. Virtualenv has not "active" when you run the pip command.

You can simply find out where it is installed by running a file search on your hard disk and check all files and folders having "goose" in their name. Then make sure that PyCharm and command line are using the same virtualenv, where goose is installed.

Comment: Hi, virtualenv was active when I installed goose. Its on folder: C:\virtual_enviroments\goose_venv\Lib\site-packages\goose_extractor-1.0.22-py2.7.egg\goose .  
to see the screenshots properly: http://i.stack.imgur.com/31tCy.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/GmYrE.png

Comment: Please check that in site-packages there is `goose` folder with `__init__.py` file. If that's not the case then just try reinstalling Goose.

Comment: PyCharm might be importing goose from somewhere else.

Comment: see previous comment. goose\\__init__.py is under another folder "goose_extractor-1.0.22-py2.7.egg". I allready tried to reinstall but its the same... on PyCharm if I right-click goose and "Go To Declaration" it takes me to same \\__init__.py I mentioned before...

Comment: Do you get the same error if you open interactive Python interpreter and type `import goose` there? Start it with `python -vvv` so you should how Python tries to import modules.

Comment: I think it could be some sort of a problem with your script, then. Maybe it does something that messes up Python's sys.path? Or maybe circular import errors.

Comment: Try run your script from the command line with `-vvv` and try to spot the difference.

Comment: Sorry, I am not a support person and I cannot sit in a chat for extended periods of time.

Comment: I run it with '-vvv' but I see no difference... It is the first line in my script so I don't think it could mess up Python's sys.path